# Hide settings bundle option from code

Tags: objective-c, ios, settings.bundle

In my app I have an option defined in the `Settings.bundle` that is used only for debugging purposes.

Is there a way of hiding this from code, for when the application is in production, without manually deleting the option from `Settings.bundle/Root.plist` ?

Something in the lines of:

```
#ifdef DEBUG

// Remove the option from the settings bundle

#else

// Show the option in (or don't actually remove the option from) the settings bundle

#endif
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're a few options:

- use a separate dev target with special Settings.bundle,
- modify Settings.bundle with a `Run script` at Build Phases for the single target adding the section for `DEBUG` configuration, check `CONFIGURATION` variable for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain there is no way to do that.

Comment: Well, he was asking for "from code". Having two separate Settings.bundles introduces a lot of problems on its own, but manipulating the script during build is a good idea.

Comment: I don't think he meant it to be really done from code but to be automated. It must be clear that there's no legit ways to modify the application bundle at runtime.